# Warning in install.packages: unable to access index for repository

Tags: r

After installing R version 4.2.0, I was suddenly unable to install packages from CRAN. This was only true from my office site which has a strong firewall.

Warning message pasted below:

```
> Warning in install.packages: unable to access index for repository
> http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib: cannot open URL
> 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES' Installing package into
> ‘C:/Users/l2863/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2’ (as ‘lib’ is
> unspecified) Warning in install.packages: unable to access index for
> repository http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib: cannot open URL
> 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
```

I reviewed the similar questions and did not find any solutions that worked.

Comment: The usual URL uses `https`, not `http`.  Maybe `http` support has been shut down.

Answer (score 9):

I found a solution [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/install-packages-unable-to-access-index-for-repository-try-disabling-secure-download-method-for-http/16578) , it worked with me using R studio on Windows

Go to Tools -> Global Options -> Packages-> Management Tab-> Uncheck "Use secure download method for HTTP"

[image]

However, if you prefer to maintain https connection for installing R packages, please refer to [this link](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/206827897) for more details

> If you have this option enabled and still receive a warning message it’s likely you need to select an alternate CRAN mirror that supports HTTPS. Mirrors currently known to support HTTPS are enumerated below in Secure CRAN Mirrors. It’s also possible that you’ve manually specified a download method or CRAN mirror in your .Rprofile that doesn't support secure downloads

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but this did not work at my worksite. I think our firewall will only work with http. (I tested it by checking for updates, seeing a couple were ready for update, then unchecked 'use secure download' and then all packages were 'up to date'.  I tried that with CRAN and Revolution Analytics. Changing back, the packages to update returned.)

Comment: In the last link there are instructions as well for "Manual Configuration via .Rprofile". They suggest using the download method "wininet" under Windows. I followed those instructions and it solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 3):

Installing CRAN packages was restored by going into the Rstudio global options and setting the Primary CRAN repository to USA (TX 1) [https] - Revolution Analytics, Dallas, TX.

I don't know why this worked, whereas selecting USA (TN) [https] - National Institute for Computational Sciences, Oak Ridge did not work.

My company's cyber security engineer stated that the TX location "seemingly points to one specific location, unlike the others."

Comment: The Rstudio mirror tends to be the best one:  it is 0-cloud in the list shown in R, or `https://cloud.r-project.org` which redirects to `https://cran.rstudio.com/`.

Comment: Yeah, if it works, I'm not advising anyone to change it. But the 0-cloud was the default I had and our firewall started blocking it. That only started with this version of R. We can go back to a previous version and that default still works. It doesn't seem to be Rstudio.

Comment: The message you showed wasn't for the default, it was for the http version.  You should only use that if you don't have https support.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing packages through the R application instead of RStudio.