# Unable to install R packages with most recent Rstudio 2023.12.1 Build 402

Tags: r, package

I just downloaded the newest version of R and Rstudio and I'm getting an error when I try to install ANY package using either the install.packages command or the install prompt from the Packages tab.

```
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/levyde/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘dplyr’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.3:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.3/PACKAGES'
```

I've never had a problem with previous versions of Rstudio and I'm finding no help in the Rstudio forums. Does anyone have any suggestions to resolve this?

Comment: Not sure, but the solutions here may help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72619247/warning-in-install-packages-unable-to-access-index-for-repository

Comment: Also note the message about needing to install Rtools.

Comment: What version of R is installed? What was the command you used to attempt to install?  Are you trying to install the source or binary version of the package?  If you installed a new version of Rstudio is the proper repository selected?

Answer (score 0):

Well sometimes things just have a way of working themselves out. I verified that I had all the correct versions installed and pointing to the correct repositories. Today, suddenly, when attempting install.packages() command, everything worked. No idea what the issue was but I can install library packages now.